# On the number of solutions of a complex system

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers

I am trying to show that the system of complex equations
$$\mathrm{Re}(z^n)=0,$$
and $$\mathrm{Im}((z-1)^n)=0$$
Has exactly $n^2$ solutions counting multiplicities.

I can see that $z=0$ is a solution with multiplicity $n$, but how can I find the other $n(n-1)$ solutions? I have really no idea. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you have no idea how to show it, then how do you know that it's true?

Comment: The paper I am currently reading states that "it is easy to show that this equation has $n^2 solutions". I tried by several ways to deduce that but I couldn't

Comment: Can you do the case $n=2$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes. The solutions are $z=0$ (with multiplicity 2) and $z=1\pm i$. So there are $4$ solutions counting multiplicities

Comment: Hint: let $\,z=r\omega\,$ with $\,|\omega|=1\,$ then the first equation gives $\,\omega^{2n}=-1\,$, and for each $\,\omega\,$ root the second equation is a polynomial of degree $\,n\,$ in $\,r\,$. Since the equations are invariant to $\,z \mapsto \bar z\,$ each root will have been counted twice.

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to see geometrically as the equation $\Re z^n=0$ has as solution all the lines passing through the origin and making the angles $\frac{(2k+1)\pi}{2n}, k=0,..n-1$ with the positive real axis, while $\Im (z-1)^n=0$ has as solution all the lines passing through $1$ and making the angles $\frac{k\pi}{n}, k=0,..n-1$ with the positive real axis; now since $\frac{2k+1}{2}$ is never an integer, the two families of lines do not contain parallel lines so they have precisely $n^2$ intersection points (where clearly the origin has multiplicity $n$ corresponding to angle $0$ in the second family)